Getting "Access Denied" error when trying to delete an object from S3 with a Lambda function
I'm trying to delete an object from S3 with the JavaScript SDK v3 using the DeleteObjectCommand(), but I'm getting an Access Denied error. The PutObjectCommand and GetObjectCommand functions work perfectly. Here is my delete object code:
import {
    S3Client,
    DeleteObjectCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"

import { configDotenv } from "dotenv";

configDotenv()

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    }
});

export const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const key = event.queryStringParameters.key
        console.log("Deleting:", key)

        const command = new DeleteObjectCommand({
            Bucket: 'somethingsold-uploads',
            Key: key
        })

        await s3Client.send(command)

        return {
            statusCode: '200',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: `Deleted image at path: ${key}`
            })
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error)
        return {
            statusCode: '500',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                error: error.message
            })
        }
    }
}

I've double checked that the key and bucket I'm passing in are correct and that the env variables are correct. But I'm getting the following error:
2024-08-13T15:59:00.691Z    400238a7-8b03-4a98-9674-ced85f765a82    INFO    Error: AccessDenied: Access Denied
at throwDefaultError (/var/task/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:840:20)
at /var/task/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:849:5
at de_CommandError (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:4743:14)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /var/task/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:35:20
at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:482:18
at async /var/task/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:320:38
at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:110:22
at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:138:14
at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/index.js:34:22 {
'$fault': 'client',
'$metadata': {
httpStatusCode: 403,
requestId: 'TDBD1YKVQ1WTATJ5',
extendedRequestId: '0rPET2J/xv0W3ammswLIAdSXFIPtKWXdBqkqRFKYFzud6et7DB8LbppFyweDH/yjm+GjPLHGONg=',
cfId: undefined,
attempts: 1,
totalRetryDelay: 0
},
Code: 'AccessDenied',
RequestId: 'TDBD1YKVQ1WTATJ5',
HostId: '0rPET2J/xv0W3ammswLIAdSXFIPtKWXdBqkqRFKYFzud6et7DB8LbppFyweDH/yjm+GjPLHGONg='
}
I have full S3 permissions for the IAM user that I'm using to delete the object in my code:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

I've attached an IAM role with full S3 permissions to my lambda function:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

And here are my bucket policies:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:user/Andy_V",
                    "arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:role/service-role/deleteImage-role-slamvt02",
                    "arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::somethingsold-uploads",
                "arn:aws:s3:::somethingsold-uploads/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I've looked everywhere and have tried everything, so I'm genuinely confused. Any help is appreciated!

Are you 100% sure that the bucket you are trying to delete the object from is actually in the same AWS account as the credentials you are using? BTW why does your Lambda function use IAM user credentials when it should be using the function's configured IAM role?

@jarmod Yes the bucket and the IAM user credentials are in the same AWS account. I'm pretty new to AWS, so configuring S3Client with IAM User credentials was the first way that I learned.

If you configure the Lambda function to have an IAM role that includes the necessary S3 permissions then your code can simply be const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-1' )};
